# Can't figure out whats wrong with Counting Cards Challenge on FreeCodeCamp

Tags: javascript

I'm currently having an issue with the counting cards challenge on FreeCodeCamp

https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/counting-cards

I created my solution using if else statements and passed 6/8 tests, these were the two that I didn't pass:

*Cards Sequence 2, J, 9, 2, 7 should return the string 1 Bet*

*Cards Sequence 2, 2, 10 should return the string 1 Bet*

Can someone explain to me why my code didn't pass these tests, I've looked at it for quite some time and I still don't get why it passed the others but not these two tests.

Thanks!

```
let count = 0;

function cc(card) {
  // Only change code below this line
if (card == 2 || card == 3 || card == 4 || card == 5 || card == 6) {
  count += 1;
  return count + " Bet";
} else if (card == 7 || card == 8 || card == 9) {
  return count + " Hold";
} else if (card == 10 || card == 'J' || card == 'Q' || card == 'K' || card == 'A') {
  count -= 1;
  return count + " Hold";
}
  // Only change code above this line
}

cc(2); cc(3); cc(7); cc('K'); cc('A');
```

Comment: you should add 1 to count in the case of the low cards, subtract 1 in case of the large cards, do NOTHING for 7, 8, and 9 ... and have a *single return* that returns the count and the HOLD/BET depending on the value of count - i.e. `return count + ' ' + (count > 0 ? 'Bet' : 'Hold')`

Answer (score 0):

I'm new, still learning. I'm guessing you already solved this one. Probably know much more than me by now haha. But all leave a correction just in case others need it.

Every time `return` is used, it makes the function ends its thing.

So in this case you are adding and right after return. Same as you subtract, you're subtracting and returning right after assign the new value. All of this without ever checking if the count is greater or less than 0.

Also, you don't really need to check for 7, 8 and 9. Because there should be no change at all in those cases. As it says, *Count Change* === 0 if card === 7, 8 or 9.

**So, doing that, it would look like this:**

```js
let count = 0;

function cc(card) {
  // Only change code below this line
  
  if (card == 2 || card == 3 || card == 4 || card == 5 || card == 6) {
    count += 1; // Instead, you can use count++, since it adds 1 with every interaction

    // The test with 7, 8 and 9 can be removed. There would be no changes if one of these cards was shown

  } else if (card == 10 || card == 'J' || card == 'Q' || card == 'K' || card == 'A') {
    count -= 1;
    // Same as count++, but now with count--. It subtracts 1 with every interaction
  }

  if (count > 0) {
    return count + " Bet"
  }
  return count + " Hold"

  // Only change code above this line
}

cc(2); cc(3); cc(7); cc('K'); cc('A');
```

**Another solution would be:**

```js
let count = 0;

function cc(card) {
  // Only change code below this line
  
  const add = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
  const sub = [ 10, 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']

  // The includes() method will check the card variable with every item of the array in which the method is called and it returns a boolean value.
  if (add.includes(card)) {
    count++
  } else if (sub.includes(card)) {
    count--
  }

  if (count > 0) {
    return count + " Bet"
  }
  return count + " Hold"

  // Only change code above this line
}

cc(2); cc(3); cc(7); cc('K'); cc('A');
```

I hope this can help someone in need.

Answer (score -1):

```js
let count = 0;

function cc(card) {
  // Only change code below this line

  let betOrHold;

  if (card >= 2 && card <=6) {
    count += 1;
    if (count >= 1) {
      betOrHold = "Bet";
    }
    else {
      betOrHold = "Hold";
    }
    return `${count} ${betOrHold}`;
  }
  else if (card >= 7 && card <=9) {
    count += 0;
    if (count <= 0) {
      betOrHold = "Hold";
    }
    else {
      betOrHold = "Bet";
    }
    return `${count} ${betOrHold}`;
  }
  else if (card === 10 || card === 'J' || card === 'Q' || card === 'K' || card === 'A') {
    count += -1;
    if (count <= 0) {
      betOrHold = "Hold";
    }
    else {
      betOrHold = "Bet";
    }
    return `${count} ${betOrHold}`;
  }

  return "Change Me";
  
  // Only change code above this line
}

cc(2); cc(3); cc(7); cc('K'); cc('A');
console.log(`${cc(2)} ${cc('J')} ${cc(9)} ${cc(2)} ${cc(7)}`);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.